# PHP - Undefined index array when I use var for index

Tags: php

I am getting a strange error when I try to access the array value via key.

This is the array I have:

```
array:4 [▼
  10 => "mr"
  20 => "ms"
  30 => "mrs"
  40 => "dr"
]
```

When I try

```
echo $titles[$user->title]
```

I am getting **Undefined index** error, (**$user->title** can have one of the 4 values from the array keys)

When I try for example

```
echo $titles[10]
```

I am getting **mr**. And when I echo **$user->title** I am getting **10**. 
Does anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Comment: What do you get using `var_dump($user->title);`?

Comment: Make sure `$user->title` is `'10'`. I suspect it contains some padding whitespace characters (spaces, newlines etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since such test returned me correct values:

```
$titles = [
  10 => "mr",
  20 => "ms",
  30 => "mrs",
  40 => "dr"
];

echo $titles[10];
echo "\n";
echo $titles['10'];
echo "\n";
```

I can only guess that You've spaces or invisible symbols in `title` attribute.

Fix is simply typecast it that will convert it to integer:

```
echo $titles[(int)$user->title]
```